# Encoding Filters in URL for deep linking purposes

Tags: angularjs, deep-linking

I'm writing an angular (1.4.8) application that must be stateful at client side.
Meaning the URL must contain all parameters to build the current view I'm looking at, so that I would be able to send this URL to someone else and he/she will get the exact same view.

I fetch data to my application from server using URL query parameters, as required when using GET method (GET and not POST is required for deep linking purposes).

For data fetching I use filters on the data, i.e. lots of these: 

`[{key: 'name', operator: '=', value: 'John'}, {key: 'age', operator: '>', value: '35'},...]`

My questions:

1. What is the best way to encode this filters array to URL?
   I've found either URIEncode(JSON.stringify(filtersArr)) of the filters string (which is ugly), or use something like jQuery.param() to get this:

   `http://host.com/app?filters[0][key]=name&filters[0][operator]=eq&filters[0][value]=John...`

   Which could be VERY long and not supported on all browsers (>2000 characters URL length).
2. Or maybe there's a better way to achieve what I want (stateful app/deep linking) without encoding this array in the URL?

Thank you

Comment: Are you open to storing the data for each link remotely and then retrieving everything via some sort of API call when the second user opens it? Could be cleaner...

Comment: If you mean to create the search criteria with POST request and get an ID for that criteria, then invoke with GET+the criteria ID, I know that method, it won't work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Not quite that I meant actually. What about sending the data parameters to a remote server with a unique object ID, and then later retrieving all the parameters on demand by referencing that ID?

Comment: I don't quite get it. You mean if I want to share the link with someone, I should save the parameter set to a server with a unique id, and when the other user would want to open that link, he will use only that id to get the parameters?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That way you don't have to worry about long URLs, because the data is actually being passed by association instead of literally. [Branch.io](https://branch.io) takes this approach.

Comment: That's what I meant in my previous comment, maybe I didn't explain myself well. That is a method I considered and I do not want to use it. Thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a string like `key+operator+value` and then join all the keys with a `,` so you'd get `name+=+John,age+>+35,key+>=+value`, when reading from the query string you can parse it back to your original array by reversing the process.